# Let $G$ be a group. Prove the equivalence relation: If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, let $a \sim b$ iff $ab^{-1} \in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, equivalence-relations

Let $G$ be a group. Prove the equivalence relation:

> If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, let $a \sim b$ iff $ab^{-1} \in H$

To prove an equivalence relation my guess is to show that reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity hold, but I am not completely sure if I am doing this correctly. So, here goes.

First we must show that if $a \sim a$ then $aa^{-1} \in H$. But $aa^{-1}=e$ and since H is a subgroup, $e$ exists in $H$.

(not sure if I am doing this correctly) Next, we must show that if $a \sim b$ then $b \sim a$, and $ba^{-1} \in H$. If $a \sim b$ then $ab^{-1} \in H$, so $a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1} \in H$. Thus, $ba^{-1} \in H$.

(not sure if I am doing this correctly) Next, we must show that if $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$, then $a \sim c$, and $ac^{-1} \in H$. But since $b \sim c$, $bc^{-1} \in H$, and so $$a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}, c, c^{-1} \in H$$ So, $ac^{-1} \in H$.

Is this even remotely correct? Is my approach correct? Since this is a biconditional statement, I am assuming I must prove the converse?

Comment: Your "guess" is to show...? That is definition, no need to guess.

Comment: I am guessing that I need to show 'so and so'. Not sure if thats what I really need to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily true that $a,b\in H$. Note that since $H$ is a group, it is closed under inverses. What is the inverse of $ab^{-1}$? Similarly, since $H$ is a group, it is closed under products. If $ab^{-1},bc^{-1}\in H$, what do you know about $(ab^{-1})(bc^{-1})$?

Comment: Ok, first: $(ab^{-1})^{-1}=ba^{-1}$ Next $(ab^{-1})(bc^{-1})=ac^{-1}$.  However, I am not understanding where this is coming from. I am not sure what this telling me? Please elaborate.

Comment: If $H$ is closed under inverses, that means that if $h\in H$, $h^{-1}\in H$. You showed that $(ab^{-1})^{-1} = ba^{-1}$. What does this say about $ba^{-1}$ in relation to $H$? Is it in $H$ or not?

Comment: Am I able to assume $ab^{-1} \in H$? If so, why?

Comment: Yes, that is the whole point. You want to show that if $a\sim b$, then $b\sim a$. If $a\sim b$, that means that $ab^{-1}\in H$, so yes you are assuming it.

Comment: I thought I was supposed to assume $a \backsim b$ then show $ab^{-1} \in H$

Comment: Why is it ok for me to assume $a \backsim b$ AND $ab^{-1} \in H$?

Comment: This is what $a \sim b \Leftrightarrow ab^{-1} \in H$ means.

Comment: But aren't we supposed to show $ab^{-1} \in H$? How can we assume that if we are to show that?

Comment: You want to prove the following: $a \sim b \Rightarrow b \sim a$. But to prove this is the same as to show $ab^{-1} \in H \Rightarrow ba^{-1} \in H$.

Comment: But if we are assuming $a \backsim b$ to begin with, then we are assuming reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity. No? Why would we need to show that if $a \backsim b$ then $b \backsim a$ if we already assuming the equivalence relation?

Comment: No. You were given a relation $a \sim b \Leftrightarrow ab^{-1} \in H$. You need to show that this relation holds all three properties of an equivalence relation. Then you will have an equivalence relation.

Comment: A relation may be very diffferent from equivalence relation. For example, the relation "$\geq$", is a relation but not symmetric.

Comment: In the first line of the answer, why is it not necessarily true that $a,b \in H$?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof of reflexivity is fine.

For symmetry, you have an error. A correct answer uses $(ab^{-1})^{-1}=ba^{-1}$. See if you can complete the proof.

You also have an error in transitivity. Use the fact that $(ab^{-1})(bc^{-1})=ac^{-1}$.

Comment: Why would I use $(ab^{-1})^{-1}$?

Comment: Is this assuming $ab^{-1} \in H$? Can we assume that?

Comment: If $a \sim b$ then $ab^{-1}$ is in $H$, by your rule. Therefore, its inverse is also in $H$ since $H$ is a subgroup. Its inverse, by the equation in my answer, is $ba^{-1}$. Therefore by your rule, $b \sim a$. Is that clear?

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you. From my understanding so far, the relation is given and I must use that relation to show it is an equivalence relation.

Comment: @JohannFranklin: Yes, exactly. And to do that you must use the properties of a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$e = b\ b^{-1} = b(a^{-1}a)b^{-1} = (ba^{-1})\underbrace{(ab^{-1})}_{\in\  H} $$

You may use the same idea for $ac^{-1}=(ab^{-1})(bc^{-1})$.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to prove this is to note that $ab^{-1} \in H$ iff $aH = bH$.

Then the equivalence classes are just the fibers of the function $f(a)=aH$.

Every relation in a set $X$ defined by $x \sim y \iff f(x) = f(y)$, where $f:X \to Z$, is an equivalence relation because equality is an equivalence relation. There is nothing really left to prove after you make this observation.

In your case, $X=G$ and $Z=\{ aH : a \in G \}$.

Comment: You might want to omit the mention of fibers since that is a fairly advanced idea.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, I'm using *fiber* just as a name for the set of inverse images of a fixed value of a function. It's a simple notion in set theory and it's quite useful to have a name for it.